# Version compatibility of jquery and knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to build a sample MVC application with Web API as my first step towards learning knockout.js I'm using knockout-3.2.0 and jquery-2.1.1 in my solution and have Internet Explorer 11 on my system.

I've included the jQuery and knockout.js files inside my code like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js" ></script>
```

However, when I run the application, get an error message:

> '$ undefined".

I'm anticipating that this issue is coming because of incompatible versions of jQuery and knockout.

Can anyone help me with this?

For the details steps which I did please visit [this dotnetcurry page](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=847). My only difference is that the jquery and knockout versions used in my sample application are different.

Also I'm building MVC5 application with entity framework 6.

I am using knockout 3.2.0 jquery <1.9.0 is compatible with this version of knockout

Comment: Why are you loading both the full and the minified jQuery files?

Answer (score 0):

Good change that the issue is happening because Jquery is impoloading due to double definition of it.. Remove either the .min.js or the .js and see if that helps.

Also if you have an custom code, make sure that it's defined under your script tag for Jquery or you will have the same issue.

Also if you are using webapi have a look into Budling from Microsoft.Web.Optimization
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389545/ASP-NET-MVC-Bundling-and-Minification

This will help with accidental script tags before jquery.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried removing either of both jquery min.js or .js but still the same issue. Also now I've placed the entire knockout code in separate js file and included in my home page but does not works

Comment: Your best tool is going to be your chrome debugger (F12) trust me... In the log there will be an error saying exactly what went wrong, click on the file reference aswell to try to find the location of the issue... Make sure that you have added the script tag for your new knockout js file you have made

Comment: your best bet for the moment imo is to look for a project (maybe this: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Architecting-Web-5dfc3130) and go through it to figure out how it works and see if you can see how yours differes from theirs... the link i provided is a bad example because it's rather large and probably hard to digest

Comment: I was using knockout 3.2.0 jquery <1.9.0 is compatible with this version of knockout